# Making fscanf ignore letters without a space before int

Tags: c, input

I'm trying (in C) to read from a file with lines like the following:

```
GFE_1
GFE_8
GFE_19
```

I want to use fscanf to ignore the letters and _ and put the number at the end into a variable.

Obviously what I have isn't right:

```
fscanf(f, "%d", number);
```

I know how to skip them if they are separated by a space but in this case I've gotten stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
fscanf(f, " %*[^A-Z]_%d", &number);
```

Or if the leading characters are always the same it's as simple as

```
fscanf(f, " GFE_%d", &number);
```

Comment: @Dawson, always check the result of `fscanf()` to ensure a successful assignment occurred (in this case the result should be 1).

Answer (score 1):

You can skip reading Alphabets and _ using this statement

`int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );`

```
fscanf(f, " %*[^A-Z]_%d", &number);
```